# VF component inputField

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, inputfield, dynamic-vf-component

So I have the following componenet,

```
<apex:component>
<apex:attribute name="label" description="This is pretty name for this input" type="String" required="true"/>
<apex:attribute name="id" description="A one word description of this label" type="String" required="true"/>
<apex:attribute name="input" description="A one word description of this label" type="String" required="true"/>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
  <label for="input{!label}" class="col-md-2 control-label">{!label}</label>
  <div class="col-md-6 form-control-wrapper">
    <apex:inputField styleClass="form-control empty" id="inputDescription" html-rows="4" value="{!input}" />
    <span class="material-input"></span>
  </div>
</div>
</apex:component>
```

The problem is that I can not save this component. I get this error,

> Error: Could not resolve the entity from  value
>   binding '{!label}'.  can only be used with SObjects,
>   or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable.

I want this to be dynamic so that I can pass whatever value I want for the inputField and it will write the same markup every time. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: When I posted this code into the DC, I got the error you did but on `{!input}`. The reason for this is that `apex:inputField` attribute `value=` has to resolve to an SObject.field, not a string

Comment: That did it!! I wasn't reading the error correctly!! If you submit as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I posted this code into the DC, I got the error you did but on `{!input}`. The reason for this is that `apex:inputField` attribute `value=` has to resolve to an SObject.field, not a string

Answer (score 0):

I was able to save the component after changing inputField to inputText.

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this will not work because I can not easily associate the inputText with the field on the object. It also does not automatically build out dropdown selects and text areas. 
How can I get the sobject so I can use inputField?